# socket io client not connecting to server using ipv4 address

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, serversocket

I'm having a problem with testing the connection when I use https://localhost:3000/ it connects successfully but I want to use socket Io client on a different device on android application to be precise I searched it up and turns out localhost wont work I have to connect using ipv4 address well I tried it but didnt work - like this http http://192.168.XX.XX:3000 for example so what is the problem why doesnt it connect please help

server code:

```
var cors = require("cors");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000 ;
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`started on ${port}`);
})

const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: { origin: "*" }
});


io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');

    socket.on('message', (message) =>     {
        console.log(message);
        io.emit('message', `${socket.id.substr(0,2)} said ${message}` );   
    });
});


require("dotenv").config();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

//routes setup
const homeGetRoute = require("./routes/test.js");
app.use("/home", homeGetRoute);
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: and also let me know if I host it on heroku and try connecting client there will it work?

Comment: You will have to paste error messages so that someone can get an idea.

Comment: problem is there r no errors in code its the connection that isnt establishing

Comment: Did u check if your ipv4 address endpoint is correct?Also How are you connecting to socket on client side? Would be helpful if you could show the relevant part.Also Do you have access to client side logs?